# Start two functions at the same time or they write different values

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm creating an app that should communicate with two external devices using BLE.
After the bond between app and devices, I should have to monitor some values, like pressure, accelerometer, etc. The devices give me data every 20ms each one.

I use a function that calls other two functions to monitor these values, like:

```
async monitoring(){
   this.readingBattery(this.device1, this.device2);
   this.monitoringDeviceRight(this.device1);
   this.monitoringDeviceLeft(this.device2);
}
```

These two functions `this.monitoringDeviceRight` and `this.monitoringDeviceLeft` do exactly the same thing.

My problem is that when I stop the monitoring the two functions have a different amount of data. In particular the right's monitoring function has less values from the other.

Do you know if I can do something to start these two functions at the same time?

EDIT1:
This is what do the monitoring function:

```
 this.monitoringDeviceRight(device1){
      this.action1 = await device1.monitorCharacteristicForService(service, this.AccGyrMg, (error, characteristic) => {
          if (error) {
            this.error(error.message);
            return;
          }
          const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
    //.....
          const [...acRight] = [2, 4, 6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
          this.arrayAcRight.push([this.timeR, ...acRight].join(":"))

          const [...gyRight] = [8, 10, 12].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));
          this.arrayGyRight.push([this.timeR, ...gyRight].join(":"))

          //.....
```

Comment: Well no clue what they actually do so hard to give an answer. Is there some callbacks to say they are ready?

Comment: What do these monitoring functions *do*?

Comment: JS is single threaded and code is executed from top to bottom. Unless we're talking about the call-stack, two functions always run one after the other. And if one takes longer to execute, it is blocking all the subsequent calls.

Comment: editing my question :)

Comment: I know, I know, premature optimization and so, plus off topic, but ain't this `const readInt16LE = index => buf.readInt16LE(index);
this.arrayAcRight.push(\`${this.timeR}:${readInt16LE(2)}:${readInt16LE(4)}:${readInt16LE(6)}\`);
this.arrayGyRight.push(\`${this.timeR}:${readInt16LE(8)}:${readInt16LE(10)}:${readInt16LE(12)}\`);` better than the **8** intermediate Arrays that you create in those 4 lines?

Comment: @Thomas Yes you are right about this :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that monitoringDeviceRight and monitoringDeviceLeft are `async` you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like so

```js
async monitoring(){
   this.readingBattery(this.device1, this.device2);
   Promise.all([monitoringDeviceRight(this.device1), monitoringDeviceLeft(this.device2)]);
}
```

If you want my opinion I believe that the devices or the functions are different because you shouldn't see that big of a difference

Comment: What's the Point of `Promise.all()` in that function? It's just another Promise that is completely ignored.

Comment: @LeonardoDrici what do you mean with I shouldn't see that big of a difference?

Comment: Anyway I have tried to use a promise.all but the situation is the same.

Comment: As I expected there would not be a difference with Promise.all you fire them at the same time. But as I thought the issue is not with the execution of the functions but rather an issue with the devices/ the function it self

Answer (score -1):

Hi I never did something like that in javascript, but I had a similiar problem in a Java program and I resolved with threads and a Barrier.

So I searched about Barriers in javascript and i found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-barrier

As they say in documentation : " This barrier will ensure that all async functions reaches the desired line at the same time."

I hope this can help you